# Store input value as a var and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

This is the code I am working from:
http://jsfiddle.net/DYfbg/12/

If you click "map" then try typing a placename it gives you autocomplete suggestions. Then if you click on one of these suggestions it tells you the co-ordinates in an alert box.

What I want to do is capture what is in the input box when the autocomplete option is clicked, and then store it as a variable. Then in the alert box, along with the co-ordinates, I want to print the input box variable into it.

I know this all sounds pretty simple but I am new to javascript so I would really appreciate some input.

This is the segment of code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    **// Store input box as variable**
    if (!place.geometry) {
        current_place = null;
        alert('Cannot find place');
        return;
    } else {
        current_place = place;
        alert('Place is at:' + place.geometry.location);
        **// Print input box varaible aswell**
    } });
```

EDIT: This is as close as I could get without getting stuck:

```
    // Set Autocomplete Location Variable equal to #loc input
    $("#loc").val(ac_location);
    // Print Autocomplete Variable
    alert(ac_location);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "place" object returned with

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

you have all info you need
Add a console.log and you'll see all infos returned.
For example:

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
console.log(place);
window.myGlobalVar = place.name;
```

Edit based on notes below:
it seems original value of inputbox is actually stored in this property:

```
autocomplete.gm_accessors_.place.lf.d
```

Comment: Your answer is good but it raises a problem. I want to do a comparison between the value that was clicked on the autocomplete and the value on the input box when the search button is clicked. 

If I use place.formatted_address it is different to the value in the input box (UK instead of united kindgom)

Comment: If I do place.name and autocomplete "London, United Kindgom" it logs "London" when the input box says "London, United Kingdom".

I am trying to check if the user changes what text is in the input box between clicking on the autocomplete and then clicking search, so using your current method, since what is logged is what is different from the input, it will always say it is different. I hope I explained this well.

Comment: Undestood. Updated post. You can retrieve original input box value, but the name, in my opinion, suggests is something not to be used.